# Can not resolve dependencies from Asp.Net WebApi (TFS classes)

Tags: c#, tfs, asp.net-core-webapi

I can not resolve the reference dependencies from TFS library:

```
private readonly TfsTeamProjectCollection _server;
private readonly WorkItemStore _workItemStore;
private WortItem _wi;
```

This is the csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
 <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
 <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
 <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
 <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
 <AssemblyName>TFSService</AssemblyName>
 <Description>service</Description>
 <Authors>sss</Authors>
 <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
 <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
 <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>   
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common" Version="12.0.21005.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" Version="16.153.0" />  
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="16.153.0" />  
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client" Version="16.153.0" />  
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient" Version="16.153.0" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

I have tried to add:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="16.153.0" />
```

But it does not work. Visual Studio can not resolve the references.

Before this web project I used the same desktop .NET framework 4.8 application with the same classes and same code. And that worked.
Now I try to porting it on web service.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past! So I know how to fix it.

In my case, we had a few old projects (.NEt 3.5) and we tried to migrate them to standard 2.0.

The problem is created, I believe, by the dependencies. So the dependencies might not be fully compatible with core 3.1.

So your options are:
1.- do not migrate, try to do it yourself.
2.- migrate, if there is a dependency that causes you issues, write it yourself.
3.- migrate, if there is a dependency that causes you issues, find another one.

Here is an article that may be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/dependencies

Just remember, different versions (core, framework, standard) and packages may mean that the signature of the methods, classes and properties is different.

Update: here is another reading for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops

It says that package is no longer available and it is being replaced by another one. I guess that the inicial project was quite old

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this mean that it will not be possible to use the specified packages in the .asp.core web api service? And what should I use Rest API requests?

Comment: hm. i read description of package: Integrate with Azure DevOps Server 2019 and Azure DevOps Services from desktop-based Windows applications.

So yes, it means that i can use it only from desktop based applications... Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, it is one of those easy things that you don't think about it but got you stack for ages. Happy to help!